# Create a docker release out of pull request

Tags: github, github-actions, dockerhub

Using github actions, I would like to create a docker release on every pull request merged to the master.
I accomplished that, however, the SHA1 of the docker image is labeled with the SHA1 of the pull-request branch.
My goal is to be able to match docker images to the repository git log sha1's.

Looks like I need some kind of action hook that only occurs when PR is actually merged/rebased to master.
I didn't find any event like this.

Is there something else I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to build docker releases off master, you could set up to trigger the workflow on push to master (which is also triggered on PRs being merged/rebased into master). Your workflow file would then begin with:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

# rest of your workflow jobs
```